# "Remote" filter not visible on mobile web

Tags: bug, mobile-web, stack-overflow-jobs

When browsing Jobs on desktop I'm able to use `Remote` filter. 
That's not the case when browsing it on mobile device.
Screenshot from iOS Safari:

> [image: screenshot of jobs and location]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional filters are available if you scroll down - because of screen size it's not obvious that certain things are below the fold!

We're planning to deprecate the mobile views in the coming months - Jobs has a pretty decent responsive view; if you scroll to the footer and select "full site" you'll get the responsive view.

Comment: Yeah I get you. I think this option is placed in Perks now. It was just weird not to find it directly as a first option.